# Old versions of Sub Sonic

Tags: subsonic

I am working on an opensource app that using SubSonic 2.0.3

I need to regenerate some of the code so I need the tool that does that.

I cannot find this version 2.0.3 of the code generator executable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the old codeplex hosting for subsonic is gone.

They haven't tagged any specific versions in the new github repository, but I bet that if you downloaded the 2.0 source you'd be able to get what you need.

http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0/tree/master

Comment: Hmm.. actually, you likely won't be able to get a specific version of it.  All I can find is 2.1 and 2.2 versions.  The master tree would be all 2.2 stuff.  You may need to email them...

Answer (score 1):

If you were just using ActiveRecord, there isn't that much difference (to my knowledge) between 2.0.3 and 2.2 so you could download and use 2.2 to update. With all the bug fixes in 2.2 from 2.0.3 I think it would be worth the effort.

Comment: Chris Cyvas (owner of dashCommerce) has said there are changes that break the solution. I must use version 2.0.3 of the subsonic.exe.